# NULL and empty column selection in WHERE clause fails

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can someone tell me why only 3rd Query works? I would understand if `NULL` and `empty column/string` get treated differently but why 2nd query doesn't work? Converting `is_disabled` and `is_terminated` into `VARCHAR(3)` doesn't help as well.

Thanks

**TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fullname` varbinary(100) NOT NULL,
  `is_disabled` enum('Yes') DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_terminated` enum('Yes') DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**DATA:**

```
id - fullname - is_disabled              - is_terminated
1  - User One - {this is just empty column} - NULL
```

**QUERY 1:**

```
SELECT id, fullname FROM users
WHERE id = '1'
    AND
    is_disabled != 'Yes' /* is_disabled <> 'Yes' */
    AND
    is_terminated != 'Yes' /* is_terminated <> 'Yes' */
```

**QUERY 2:**

```
SELECT id, fullname FROM users
WHERE id = '1'
    AND
    is_disabled = '' /* is_disabled IS NULL */
    AND
    is_terminated = '' /* is_terminated IS NULL */
```

**QUERY 3:**

```
SELECT id, fullname FROM users
WHERE id = '1'
    AND
    (is_disabled = '' OR is_disabled IS NULL)
    AND
    (is_terminated = '' OR is_terminated IS NULL)
```

Comment: you can change this `(is_disabled = '' OR is_disabled IS NULL)` to this `ifnull(is_disabled,'') = ''`

Comment: @Justin Althouth this is syntactically valid, such a condition is likely to prevent the use of an index on `is_disabled`. Prefer the first form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything compared to `NULL` is `NULL`.

```
SELECT NULL = 1; -- NULL
SELECT NULL = NULL; -- NULL
SELECT NULL <> 1; -- NULL
SELECT NULL <> NULL; -- NULL
SELECT NULL = ''; -- NULL
SELECT NULL <> ''; -- NULL
```

And `NULL` is not `TRUE` (nor `FALSE`).

There is a "[null-safe comparator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)" (`<=>`) but I would always prefer a more explicit `IS NULL` (but this is a personal taste).

```
SELECT NULL <=> NULL; -- 1 (TRUE)
SELECT NULL <=> 42; -- 0 (FALSE)
```

Comment: `NULL` evaluates as `FALSE` isn't exactly correct since `NOT NULL = NULL` doesn't evaluate as `TRUE`. The better way would be to say "`NULL` does not evaluate as `TRUE`". Ternary logic can be so confusing....

Comment: Yes indeed, and it doesn't evaluate as `FALSE` either. In fact, it does evaluate as... `NULL` ;) Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, `NULL` is different from an `Empty String`. So `column = ''` is not equal to `column IS NULL`.

The third query works as you expect because of the `OR` condition. Let me illustrate it.

```
d = '1' AND (is_disabled = '' OR is_disabled IS NULL) AND (is_terminated = '' OR is_terminated IS NULL)
 TRUE   AND (          TRUE   OR           FALSE)     AND (FALSE OR TRUE)
 TRUE   AND                  TRUE                     AND      TRUE
 .... making the condition ALL TRUE
```

The second query fails because of this condition `is_terminated = ''` which returns to `NULL` making the whole `WHERE` condition `NULL`.